# Add function in object

Tags: javascript, function, object, methods

I try to add function to the object. Why does't it work? The result is undefined. Please help.

```html
<html>
<body>

<script>
  var calc = function(){
    this.num1 = 5,
    this.num2 = 5,
    compute = function( ) {
      this.result = this.num1 * this.num2;
    }
  };
  
  var myObj =[];
  for(var i=0; i<5; i++){myObj.push(new calc())};
  //calc.compute();
  
   document.write(myObj.compute);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You use `this.num1` correctly, yet you're just defining `compute` as a local (actually, global) variable instead of a public method.

Comment: `myObj` is `Array`, and to get items from Array you should use index from `0` to `n` - `myObj[0]`

Comment: Aside, why do you want 5 duplicate functions? Wouldn't it make more sense to pass in parameters when you're creating an object so `compute` does more than add the same numbers together?

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of immediate issues. First, constructors should be written in the style `function Calc(args)` to distinguish them from other functions, and to also solve scope/context issues.

Second, your method should be `this.compute`.

Third, while adding the numbers to a `result` variable is fine, from the rest of your code you look like you want to return something from `compute` but you're not.

Finally, why do you want to create five *identical* objects? I've corrected but also updated your code a little bit below to show you what I mean.

```
function Calc(first, second) {

   // assign the arguments to num1 and num2
   this.num1 = first;
   this.num2 = second;
   this.compute = function() {

     // we return the result rather than assigning it
     return this.num1 * this.num2;
   }
};

var myObj = [];

// here we use i and 5 as the new object parameters
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  myObj.push(new Calc(i, 5));
};

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(myObj[i].compute()); // 0, 5, 10, 15, 20
};
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pcx0cnfp/)

Now, as deceze suggests, separating out the method and defining it on the prototype is also a good idea, so you'd end up with the following code:

```
function Calc(first, second) {
   this.num1 = first;
   this.num2 = second;
};

Calc.prototype.compute = function() {
   return this.num1 * this.num2;
}
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xohxxran/1/)

Comment: Now if you'd also define `compute` on the prototype... :)

Comment: That's part of tomorrow's lesson.

Answer (score 0):

Try associating the function with the object with `this` keyword. Currently compute function is not associated with the object.

Also you need to return the result and accessing  object by index

So correct one will be

```
    var calc = function() {
      this.num1 = 5,
        this.num2 = 5,
        this.compute = function() {
          this.result = this.num1 * this.num2;
return this.result;
        }
    };

    var myObj = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      myObj.push(new calc())
    };
    //calc.compute();

    document.write(myObj[0].compute());
```

Comment: Is there some particular reason you are putting commas in between statements instead of semi-colons?

Comment: @torazaburo I just copy pasted the code and found it working. I mostly use semicolumn . But I found both of them working but I don't know is there any major differences . If you know please share

Answer (score -2):

#### Issues:

1. Missing parenthesis `document.write(myObj.compute);`. It should be `document.write(myObj.compute());`.
2. `myObj` is an array of objects of type `Calc`. So you will need index to access any property of object. `myObj[0].compute()`.
3. Missing return statement in `compute` function. You are assigning value to `this.results` but not returning anything. I have removed `results` and have added `return` statement.

Following code represents the same:

```js
var calc = function() {
  // Store current context
  var self = this;
  self.num1 = 5,
    self.num2 = 5,
    compute = function() {
      return self.num1 * self.num2;;
    }

  // public properties...
  return {
    compute: compute
  }
};

var myObj = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  myObj.push(new calc())
};
//calc.compute();

document.write(myObj[0].compute());
```

Comment: @Downvoter, please tell what I'm missing. Would appreciate to learn something new.

Comment: You don't seem to quite understand how `this` and `new` works. #1 and #2 are plain false.

Comment: Thanks @deceze. My bad. Forgot this holds object reference of calling object. Will update my answer. Don't know how I missed it.